# Почему может не работать в ие 11 WebGL? THREE.WebGlRenderer

Tags: three.js, webgl

В ие11  не работает WebGL анимация.
В консоли такие ошибки есть 
Можно ли как-то избежать этого?

THREE.WebGlRenderer: WEBGL_depth_texture extension not supported
THREE.WebGlRenderer: OES_texture_half_float extension not supported
THREE.WebGlRenderer: OES_texture_half_float_linear extension not supported

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от версии WebGL которую использует IE11, например, у меня версия IE 11.371 (WebGL 0.94) и она поддерживает OES_texture_float и OES_texture_float_linear, но не поддерживает WEBGL_depth_texture. Edge поддерживает WebGL 1.0 и там есть поддержка всех трех расширений. Не думаю что IE11 будут обновлять до поддержки WebGL 1.0, когда есть Edge, хотя все может быть.

Думаю стоит делать проверку на версии браузера и если IE11 то не подключать WEBGL_depth_texture.

Comment: а как его можно отключить?